# VF page is opening as modal in Salesforce lightning experience on an action button click

Tags: lightning-experience

VF page is opening as modal in Salesforce lightning experience on an action button click. When I look at the generated code,my code is there in an iframe which the salesforce generated modal contains.

I need to perform the same operation on the cancel button(which is on my vf page) as of the cross icon (of the generated modal). I tried getting the modal element by class name and calling the same click event on cancel button,which is getting called on cross icon.

The problem here is, I am not able to access any element outside the iframe. It throws

> 'Blocked a frame with origin "https://c.na34.visual.force.com" from
>   accessing a cross-origin frame.'

error. window.parent does not help either. Please provide suggestion to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [This](http://www.salesforcegeneral.com/salesforce-modal-dialog-box/) example. It'll work for you.

Comment: put this as comment, if you are allowed to

Comment: Just got the allowance at 50. Will do next time. Thanks.